# How to increase the spacing between labels and the chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

How can we increase the spacing between the x-axis and the chart in chartjs

so far

```
 options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [
                        {
                        ticks: { display: true },
                        gridLines: {
                            display: true,
                            drawBorder: false,
                            drawTicks: false,
                            // color: "#fff",   
                        },
                        
                    }],
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this helps? (Look for `padding`) https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration

Comment: That actually works, thanks fam @BrunoMonteiro

Comment: Added as a proper answer to follow the correct SO process :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the `padding` attribute available in the axes styling:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration